# how to get the date 30 days before todays date from database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

consider i have a table named `Products`.

| `ProductID` | `ProductName` | `ExpDate` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Coca Cola | 2021-6-6 |
| 1002 | Pepsi | 2021-5-8 |

I wanted to get the `ExpDate` from each of the `Products` and get the 30 days before that date.

for example; the 1st one `ExpDate` is 2021-6-6, so minus 30 days = 2021-5-5

Comment: You should add more information. It is not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Use the DATEADD function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Your math is wrong. May has 31 days - a boundary that is crossed for your June calculation. So 30 days before June 6 is May 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateAdd function to subtract 30 days from a date field.

```
   Select ProductName, ExpDate, dateadd(day,-30,ExpDate) as '30Daysbefore' 
   from Products
```

Comment: This was a more complete answer so I removed mine.  But. An alias for a column can't start with a number.

Comment: True, I was just winging it. :)